# Fit four authors across on one row in "sigplanconf" style?

Tags: formatting, titles, acm

Is there some hack out there to make it possible to fit four authors across in one row in the `sigplanconf` class?

No matter how short each author's name, affiliation, and email is, by default the style fits only 3 authors across in one row.

Having four authors results in a massive amount of wasted space.

Ideally, I'd like to have this:

```
                  Article Title

Fname Lname   Fname Lname   Fname Lname   Fname Lname
   dept           dept         dept          dept
  school         school       school        school
 email@edu     email@edu     email@edu     email@edu


     Abstract                .....................
....................         .....................
....................         .....................
....................         .....................
```

But this is what I have instead:

```
                  Article Title

Fname Lname        Fname Lname       Fname Lname   
   dept               dept              dept       
  school             school            school      
 email@edu          email@edu         email@edu    

                   Fname Lname
                      dept
                     school
                    email@edu

      Abstract               .....................
....................         .....................
....................         .....................
....................         .....................
```

Is there something I can do to `\authorinfo` to force them to be wider, or to squeeze 4 to a column?

My document looks like:

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt]{sigplanconf}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the class `sigplanconf` typesets the authors in rows and uses maximum three authors per row (this is done using the macro `\@titleauthors`); to change this behaviour, you need to redefine `\maketitle` and to define a command to allow typesetting four authors in a row (the command `\@ivtitleauthors` in my example, which was defined in a similar fashion to the default `\@titleauthors` command):

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt]{sigplanconf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def \@ivtitleauthors#1#2#3#4{%
  \if \@andp{\@emptyargp{#2}}{\@emptyargp{#3}}%
    \noindent \@setauthor{40pc}{#1}{\@false}\par
  \else\if \@emptyargp{#3}%
    \noindent \@setauthor{17pc}{#1}{\@false}\hspace{3pc}%
              \@setauthor{17pc}{#2}{\@false}\par
  \else\if \@emptyargp{#4}%
    \noindent \@setauthor{17pc}{#1}{\@false}\hspace{3pc}%
              \@setauthor{17pc}{#3}{\@false}\par
  \else
    \noindent \@setauthor{9.3333pc}{#1}{\@false}\hspace{1.5pc}%
              \@setauthor{9.3333pc}{#2}{\@false}\hspace{1.5pc}%
              \@setauthor{9.3333pc}{#3}{\@false}\hspace{1.5pc}%
              \@setauthor{9.3333pc}{#4}{\@true}\par
    \relax
  \fi\fi\fi
  \vspace{20pt}}
\def \@maketitle {%
  \begin{center}
  \@settitlebanner
  \let \thanks = \titlenote
  {\leftskip = 0pt plus 0.25\linewidth
   \rightskip = 0pt plus 0.25 \linewidth
   \parfillskip = 0pt
   \spaceskip = .7em
   \noindent \LARGE \bfseries \@titletext \par}
  \vskip 6pt
  \noindent \Large \@subtitletext \par
  \vskip 12pt
  \ifcase \@authorcount
    \@latex@error{No authors were specified for this paper}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\or
    \@ivtitleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}{iv}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\@titleauthors{x}{}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\@titleauthors{x}{xi}{}\or
    \@titleauthors{i}{ii}{iii}\@titleauthors{iv}{v}{vi}%
                  \@titleauthors{vii}{viii}{ix}\@titleauthors{x}{xi}{xii}%
  \else
    \@latex@error{Cannot handle more than 12 authors}{}%
  \fi
  \vspace{1.75pc}
  \end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}
\authorinfo{Fname Lname}
           {school}
           {email@edu}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are writing for a journal, make sure that this kind of change is accepted; otherwise, maintain the original layout.

Comment: Incredible! Works like a charm! Thanks so much!